# resolving css text media query

Tags: html, css, text, media-queries

I am trying to make my text -movies , tv shows , games responsive . what should I do? I tried media query but I think I got it wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Papaya | Home</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -4000;
}
body{
font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;}

a:hover {color: red;}
a { text-decoration: none; color:white; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; }

#one {
position: fixed;
top:180px;
left:200px;
}

#two {
position: fixed;
top:180px;
left:570px;
}

#three {
position: fixed;
top:180px;
left:900px;
}

h1{font-size:70px}

}
</style>
</head>

<body >
<div id="one">
<h1><a href="movies.html"  style="text-decoration:none">MOVIES</a></h1></div>

 <div id="two"> 
<h1><a href="games.html"  style="text-decoration:none">GAMES</a></h1></div>

<div id="three">
<h1><a href="tvshows.html"  style="text-decoration:none">TV SHOWS</a></h1></div>

<div align="center"><img src="images/ball.jpg" class="bg" alt="LOADING.."></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, write HTML and CSS n separate files. It's considered best practice in web development ;) Then, the best way to add responsiveness to a website is to have Bootstrap installed. 
Copy and past this to the head of your html document:

This is a CDN (Content Delivery System) link. It will pull the bootstrap features from their website and allow you to add responsiveness to your site.

Here is the Bootstrap documentation link:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

My answer might seem a little long and complicated, but it's not. This is how professionals and companies make modern, responsive websites today! Hope this helps.

Comment: OKAY THANKS ILL TRY IT NOW SOON.. THANK YOU . FOR TIME BEING ILL KEEP THE CSS TOGETHER...

Comment: I AM GETTING CONFUSED CAN YOU LET ME KNOW WHAT TO DO EXACTLY. IT WOULD BE OF GREAT HELP..